# Kubernetes imagePullSecrets not working; getting "image not found"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerhub

I have an off-the-shelf Kubernetes cluster running on AWS, installed with the `kube-up` script. I would like to run some containers that are in a private Docker Hub repository. But I keep getting a "not found" error:

```
 > kubectl get pod
NAME                      READY     STATUS                                        RESTARTS   AGE
maestro-kubetest-d37hr    0/1       Error: image csats/maestro:latest not found   0          22m
```

I've created a secret containing a `.dockercfg` file. I've confirmed it works by running the script posted [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/499#issuecomment-131162957):

```
 > kubectl get secrets docker-hub-csatsinternal -o yaml | grep dockercfg: | cut -f 2 -d : | base64 -D > ~/.dockercfg
 > docker pull csats/maestro
latest: Pulling from csats/maestro
```

I've confirmed I'm not using [the new format of .dockercfg script](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/12626), mine looks like this:

```
> cat ~/.dockercfg
{"https://index.docker.io/v1/":{"auth":"REDACTED BASE64 STRING HERE","email":"eng@csats.com"}}
```

I've tried [running the Base64 encode on Debian instead of OS X](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/499#issuecomment-132504379), no luck there. (It produces the same string, as might be expected.)

Here's the YAML for my Replication Controller:

```
---
kind: "ReplicationController"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "maestro-kubetest"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: "maestro"
    ecosystem: "kubetest"
    version: "1"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "maestro"
        ecosystem: "kubetest"
        version: "1"
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: "docker-hub-csatsinternal"
      containers:
        - name: "maestro"
          image: "csats/maestro"
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"

      restartPolicy: "Always"
      dnsPolicy: "ClusterFirst"
```

`kubectl version`:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.3", GitCommit:"61c6ac5f350253a4dc002aee97b7db7ff01ee4ca", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.3", GitCommit:"61c6ac5f350253a4dc002aee97b7db7ff01ee4ca", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In your example you're pulling two different images - did you try pulling maestro?

Comment: Good catch -- reran the command with the right image. Same result.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.. did you find the solution?

Comment: If it's still useful to you two months later, yes I did. Heh.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Docker generates a `config.json` file in `~/.docker/`
It looks like:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "ZmFrZXBhc3N3b3JkMTIK",
            "email": "email@company.com"
        }
    }
}
```

what you actually want is:

```
{"https://index.docker.io/v1/": {"auth": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "email": "email@company.com"}}
```

note 3 things:

- 1) there is no `auths` wrapping
- 2) there is `https://` in front of the
  URL
- 3) it's **one line**

then you **base64** encode that and use as data for the `.dockercfg` name

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata: 
  name: registry
data:
  .dockercfg: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==
type: kubernetes.io/dockercfg
```

Note again the `.dockercfg` line is **one line** (base64 tends to generate a multi-line string)

Comment: You got me to the solution -- turns out my problem was that my secret was `type: Opaque` instead of `type: kubernetes.io/dockercfg`. Cheers.

Answer (score 28):

Another possible reason why you might see "image not found" is if the namespace of your secret doesn't match the namespace of the container.

For example, if your Deployment yaml looks like

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mydeployment
  namespace: kube-system
```

Then you must make sure the Secret yaml uses a matching namespace:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: ****
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

If you don't specify a namespace for your secret, it will end up in the default namespace and won't get used. There is no warning message. I just spent hours on this issue so I thought I'd share it here in the hope I can save somebody else the time.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue here. The only difference is that I actually WANT the secret to be in the default namespace as I don't want to create it for all namespaces.

Is there a way to reference to a secret the default namespace while the ingress is created inside a namespace?

Comment: Including `type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson` was the missing secret sauce that none of the other answers around the internet seemed to include. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 6):

Another reason you might see this error is due to using a kubectl version different than the cluster version (e.g. using kubectl 1.9.x against a 1.8.x cluster).

The format of the secret generated by the *kubectl create secret docker-registry* command has changed between versions.

A 1.8.x cluster expect a secret with the format:

```
{  
   "https://registry.gitlab.com":{  
      "username":"...",
      "password":"...",
      "email":"...",
      "auth":"..."
   }
}
```

But the secret generated by the 1.9.x kubectl has this format:

```
{  
   "auths":{  
      "https://registry.gitlab.com":{  
         "username":"...",
         "password":"...",
         "email":"...",
         "auth":"..."
      }
   }
}
```

So, double check the value of the .dockercfg data of your secret and verify that it matches the format expected by your kubernetes cluster version.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really solved my problem. I fiddled around with minikube on windows, and while chocolatey installs kubectl-cli version 1.9 by default minikube for windows still is 1.8.
Always run kubectl version and double check for matching versions.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. MrE's answer is on the right track but it doesn't mention **why** the format is different. Thanks so much eschnou, you finally solved the problem that had me banging my head against the wall for 2 days.

Comment: I don't understand how the previous version/format can't also be supported. It's so easy to allow both and instead the internet is full of people struggling

Answer (score 3):

I've been experiencing the same problem. What I did notice is that in the example (https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod) .dockercfg has the following format:

```
{ 
   "https://index.docker.io/v1/": { 
     "auth": "ZmFrZXBhc3N3b3JkMTIK", 
     "email": "jdoe@example.com" 
   } 
}
```

While the one generated by docker in my machine looks something like this:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "ZmFrZXBhc3N3b3JkMTIK",
            "email": "email@company.com"
        }
    }
}
```

By checking at the source code, I found that there is actually a test for this use case (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/6def707f9c8c6ead44d82ac8293f0115f0e47262/pkg/kubelet/dockertools/docker_test.go#L280)

I confirm you that if you just take and encode "auths", as in the example, it will work for you.

Probably the documentation should be updated. I will raise a ticket on github.

Comment: Hmm -- didn't solve my problem. I believe I tried both formats originally.