# ImagePullBackOff: Kubernetes error with Nexus based Private Registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nexus, docker-registry

I had initially thought this was the same as: [Kubernetes imagePullSecrets not working; getting "image not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510310/kubernetes-imagepullsecrets-not-working-getting-image-not-found)

However, even disabling authentication (to avoid the need for secrets) still produces the same error.

So, Kubernetes trying to pull images from Nexus Docker registry keeps producing the kubernetes error:

```
"Failed to pull image "nexus.mydomain.co.uk/nginx": Error: image nginx:latest not found"
```

This is also reflected in the Nexus logs:

```
2016-06-22 14:51:26,929+0000 WARN  [qtp556619582-227] docker org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V1Handlers - Error: GET /v1/repositories/nginx/images: 404 - org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V1Exception$ImagesNotFound: images not found
```

I can't get onto the kube boxes to try a pull, however, when I run "docker pull" from my mac command line all is well and good.

Comment: did you build the image locally, tagged and pushed? if you do docker pull and you built it locally, you may be pulling from you local computer. also try docker pull -a to pull all tags. maybe you don't have a 'latest' tag on your image

Comment: I have cleaned my local images so I'm convinced it's not a residual image. I can also see that the image is in Nexus as expected.

Comment: It'd be easier to debug if you can try `docker pull` from the k8s node.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I was hoping however we provisioned the instance using kube up.