# Kubernetes image_pull_secrets only uses secret from same namespace, is there other way so the secret doesn't need to be created to all namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm coming from the following thread and bump up the question in the comment

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40997561/2641128

`The only difference is that I actually WANT the secret to be in the default namespace as I don't want to create it for all namespaces. Is there a way to reference to a secret the default namespace while the ingress is created inside a namespace?`

Any solution for this issue in 2021?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing changed and [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) is still a namespace defendant object...

[Secret restrictions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#restrictions)

> Secret resources reside in a namespace. Secrets can only be referenced
> by Pods in that same namespace.